# Collapsible Table Cells with Xib

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

Right now I have a table using Xib loading data from Firebase which is working well. I am hoping to enhance its functionality by having  collapsible cells (based on single tap of the cell).

My question is that is it possible using Xib for this?
If yes, how do I implement it? With 2 separate xibs (method 1) or just with 1 xib and review the second part (method 2) or load a different xib all together (method 3).

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible with 1 xib you need to give the collaps-able part a height constraint and play with it's constant accordingly inside `cellForRowAt`

```
cell.heightcon.constant = items[indexPath.row].show ? 200 : 0
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
return cell
```

You can also make 2 constraints 1 links the top visible part to the collabs-able part and the other links it to the bottom of the cell and play with their `isActive` property